# Table Lock Escalation - Performance Questions

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2017, locking, lock-escalation

I have few questions on table lock escalations, please confirm or disprove:

1. Index Scan operator in a query results in Table Lock Escalation ? always or not (small tables) ?
2. When Shared lock is escalated to a table level, it blocks small updates and deletes ? inserts as well ?
3. Is it possible to get counts of table `lock_escalation` event, grouped by login and then by table ? For example:

> login1 - table1 - 11
> login1 - table2 - 5
> login2 - table1 - 29
> etc...

Extended Events seemed to allow only one level of grouping if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will preface by saying: a Table Lock is generally taken only when the number of locks on a single table hits 5,000, or 40% of lock memory has been used. [See the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#lock-escalation-thresholds) for further details.

With that in mind:

1. An Index Scan does not *necessarily* take a table lock, it will only do so once it hits the thresholds. This may not happen even on a large table, if there is a row-goal on the scan (for example `TOP` or `EXISTS`). The total size of the table appears immaterial, only the number of rows actually read.
2. An `S` lock on the Table level is not compatible with an `IX` or an `X` lock, one of which would be attempted by DML such as `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. However, a `U` lock can still be taken, which means that DML can still find rows to modify, but will have to wait to actually attempt the modification.